# Unpacking UE4 .pak's?

Tags: modding, unreal, assets

Is there any way to properly unpack/repack resources of UDK-based games *(.pak files)*? .
From what I've tried already, gildor.org's viewer seems to skip/ignore these .pak's (also, UDK, which is UE3 though, wont read renamed .pak->.uassets).

Answer (score 4):

You can just use UnrealPak.

```
    Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealPak.exe somepak.pak -extract X:\extract\here
```